# Node.js find out visitors entry page, current page and exit page?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a small server in Node with socket.io, and i want to find out the entry, current and exit -pages. My idea is to store then inside of the user session for later use.

My problem is that i do not know where to get this info, does anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean by entry and exit pages?

Comment: Entry page: What page a user enters on your page, and exit on what page the user left the entire page.

Comment: An entry page can for example be the main page like index.php and exit page contact.php

Comment: I want to track the path the user takes over the domain and where he/she currently is

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this.

[node-sessions](https://github.com/dresende/node-sessions)

Answer (score -1):

The entry page can be taken from `Referer` HTTP header (if present).

The current page is `request.url`

The exit page should be got inside browser when changing the `window.location`